# Javascript / ASP.NET MVC 4 - Using C# Strings in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, string

I need to be able to access strings held in my C# code in JavaScript. To test, I have tried displaying a message box with the C# string in JavaScript (I am using this string literal and the message box as an example scenario):

```
alert(<%: "TEST" %>);
```

When this code runs, no message box is displayed. On the other hand, a message box is displayed with this code:

```
alert(<%: 6 %>);
```

Why is it that I can use integers but not strings? Is there any way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add quotes around the string; otherwise, the browser sees `alert(TEST);`, which is incorrect. To prevent cross-site scripting attacks, you also need to properly escape special characters. Calling [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784638.aspx) lets you do both:

```
alert(<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("TEST", true) %>);
```

**Note:** If this JavaScript snippet appears inside an HTML attribute like `onclick`, you may need to change `<%=` to `<%:` so that the double quotes are also HTML encoded.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that I can use integers but not strings?

Because you need to put strings in *quotes*:

```
alert("<%: "TEST" %>");
```

The key here, as always, is to look at what the browser actually receives. With your original code, what the browser sees is:

```
alert(TEST);
```

...which is trying to use the *variable* `TEST`, not a literal string.

Now in the above, I've assumed the string won't have any `"` in it or other things that aren't valid within a JavaScript string literal. That's not usually a good assumption to make.

If you're using a recent version of .Net or using JSON.Net (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719642/how-to-handle-json-in-c) for details), you can output the string using a JSON serializer, which will ensure that anything within it that may be problematic is properly encoded/escaped. For instance, with `JSON.Net`, you might use:

```
// With JSON.Net
alert(<%: JsonConvert.ToString("TEST") %>);

// With a recent version of .Net
alert(<%: HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("TEST", true) %>);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how this translates into JavaScript:

```
alert(<%: "TEST" %>);
```

becomes

```
alert(TEST);
```

This is a problem because it assumes there is a variable named `TEST` that you'd like to display the value of, but most likely, `TEST` is undefined. What you probably want to do is this:

```
alert('<%: "TEST" %>');
```

But since this is MVC 4, you can use the [`Json.Encode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method to be a little cleaner, like this:

```
alert(<%: Json.Encode("TEST") %>);
```

Both of thse will translate to

```
alert('TEST');
```

This should display a message box with the string `'TEST'`.